# -[XBMessage messageHash]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xmpp, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I've integrated following library from Cocoapods, You may find the code and its sample code at https://github.com/EugeneNguyen/XBChatModule

```
pod 'XBChatModule'
```

This library is used to integrate XMPP Chat in Xcode project.
I also added suggested code from its ReadMe file. For your reference I am pasting it below

**AppDelegate.m**

```
    [[XBChatModule sharedInstance] setUsername:@"admin"];
    [[XBChatModule sharedInstance] setPassword:@"admin"];
    [[XBChatModule sharedInstance] setHost:@"sflashcard.com"];
    [[XBChatModule sharedInstance] connect];

    [[XBChatModule sharedInstance] setAvatarFormat:@"http://dev.sflashcard.com/images/mantis_logo.png?test=%@"];
    [[XBChatModule sharedInstance] setAvatarPlaceHolder:[UIImage imageNamed:@"girl_9"]];
```

The View controller is inherited from `XBMessageViewController`

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.jidStr = @"binh.nx@sflashcard.com";
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadData) name:@"XBChatModuleNewAvatar" object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)reloadData
{
    [self.collectionView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

The code works fine until I send a message. Whenever I press send button, it crashes the app by throwing following error in console

```
2015-09-01 17:20:41.742 Test[16064:251944] -[XBMessage messageHash]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffc91cc4180
2015-09-01 17:20:41.800 Test[16064:251944] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[XBMessage messageHash]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffc91cc4180'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011260aa75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001122a3bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112611d1d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001125697ef ___forwarding___ + 495
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112569578 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Test                                0x000000010ebaf7ed -[JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout messageBubbleSizeForItemAtIndexPath:] + 301
    6   Test                                0x000000010ebb02a7 -[JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:] + 71
    7   Test                                0x000000010ebc5c93 -[JSQMessagesViewController collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:] + 131
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001116369be -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _getSizingInfos] + 988
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000111637839 -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _fetchItemsInfoForRect:] + 526
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001116332b7 -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout collectionViewContentSize] + 66
    11  Test                                0x000000010ebc2d85 -[JSQMessagesViewController scrollToBottomAnimated:] + 325
    12  Test                                0x000000010ebc2c34 -[JSQMessagesViewController finishReceivingMessageAnimated:] + 388
    13  Test                                0x000000010ebc2aa0 -[JSQMessagesViewController finishReceivingMessage] + 48
    14  Test                                0x000000010ebfaac3 -[XBMessageViewController loadDataToTable] + 1507
    15  Test                                0x000000010ebf9be9 -[XBMessageViewController viewDidLoad] + 73
    16  Test                                0x000000010ead0760 -[ViewController viewDidLoad] + 96
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000111104580 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 738
    18  UIKit                               0x000000011110477e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000111023509 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
    20  UIKit                               0x00000001110238a1 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 247
    21  UIKit                               0x000000011102ff8c -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000110fda0c2 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2732
    23  UIKit                               0x0000000110fdce3e -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1349
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000110fdbd35 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    25  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000115aab243 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011253fc7c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001125359c5 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112535183 __CFRunLoopRun + 851
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112534bc6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    30  UIKit                               0x0000000110fdb7a2 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    31  UIKit                               0x0000000110fde580 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    32  Test                                0x000000010ead06d3 main + 115
    33  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000112b3c145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I understand it says, that I haven't implemented the function `messageHash` in Class `XBMessage` , but the same code works fine in the sample code that I download from [Github](https://github.com/EugeneNguyen/XBChatModule). Kindly help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library that `XBChatModule` is based on has since been updated. If you look at the history of the protocol that `XBMessage` conforms to: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/commits/develop/JSQMessagesViewController/Model/JSQMessageData.h you can see that the method `messageHash` has been made required since the `XBChatModule` was written.

As such, I recommend contacting the developers of `XBChatModule` and get them to update their code or, alternatively, implement your own `messageHash` method.

Comment: Thanks @michaelrccurtis, In fact I don't know what should be in messageHash, although I read the documentation that was in the declaration of the method. Can you suggest me a link of such tutorial that can elaborate what should be in the "messageHash" function ?

Comment: I suggest that to begin with you just use the NSObject `hash` property, i.e in `messageHash` just have `return self.hash`, as this is the default behaviour now implemented in the JSQ library. You might want to take note of the issue here: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/631 which lists reasons why you might want to use a different implementation, but that depends on your particular set up.

Comment: Thanks, that error is not repeating but a new error is now raised , it says "Invalid parameter not satisfying: messageSenderId != nil"  , the error is in Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Controllers/JSQMessagesViewController.m:452

Comment: This means that the `senderId` is not being set, either in the `MessageViewController` or in the message itself, depending on where the error is arising. I recommend making this a new question, although I suspect that the problem is again that the XBChatModule has not been updated.

Comment: Ok @michaerccurtis. Thanks for your help. I am trying to solve it by my own otherwise I will post it tomorrow.