# Invalid parameter not satisfying: messageSenderId != nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xmppframework, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I integrated `'XBChatModule'` Library from Cocoapods into my project.

When I run the code for the first time, It crashed the app by throwing following error [-[XBMessage messageHash]: unrecognized selector sent to instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32331059/1030951) and it got resolved by changing `XBMessage.m` file as below

**XBMessage.m**

```
- (NSUInteger)messageHash
{
    return self.hash;
}
```

But this produces new issue saying

```
Assertion failure in -[ChatMessagesController collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:], /Users/Neelacharya/Harshit/LIve Projects/Project/V1/Source/Project/Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Controllers/JSQMessagesViewController.m:452

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: messageSenderId != nil'

*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011161ca75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001112b1bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011161c8da +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010edcfb6f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   CinchGaming                         0x000000010d7be3c5 -[JSQMessagesViewController collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] + 693
    5   CinchGaming                         0x000000010d7f5f6d -[XBMessageViewController collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] + 141
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001102b9fab -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 244
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001102bb6e4 -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 3445
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001102bf391 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 243
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010fd041c3 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
    10  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f9d2c58 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
    11  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f9c787e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f9c76ee _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f93536e _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f936482 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390
    15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f936aed _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111551507 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111551460 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111547293 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111546bc6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000112796a58 GSEventRunModal + 161
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010fc8a580 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    22  CinchGaming                         0x000000010d67e463 main + 115
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000111b4e145 start + 1
    24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I understand the reason of crash is the member **messageSenderId is nil at 452'th line of JSQMessagesViewController.m** file. But I don't know why does it occur and how to get it resolved.

I also reported as issue to the authors at [Github](https://github.com/EugeneNguyen/XBChatModule/issues/2), but couldn't get response.

I would appreciate if you can help me to solve the problem.

Comment: OK so `messageSenderId == nil`.  Now you need to figure out what would normally populate it.  You also need to know why you had to provide an implementation of `XBMessage messageHash` (find the author and ask him/her).  It's all a bit broad for stackoverflow, however.

Comment: Well when I saw the sample code, it is old version of the library and it doesn't need to implement the above method that I did, But the code from cocoa pod as library, requires the method to be implemented. I also posted the issue to the author (https://github.com/EugeneNguyen/XBChatModule/issues/2) but he is not responding.

Answer (score 0):

It think the application is crashing on this line:

```
NSString *messageSenderId = [messageItem senderId];
NSParameterAssert(messageSenderId != nil);
```

When I dig into that I found that the `senderId`is being set from `XBMessageViewController`'s `loadDataToTable` method. The only reason I can find the value for `senderId` is nil is you aren't setting the values for `jidStr` and `senderId`.

You will require to set `jidStr` and `senderId` and `XBMessageViewController`, where `jidStr` is receiver and `senderId` is self user.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You need to register your class like `[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];`

Comment: why registration ? the parent class of the view controller has already done the same.

Comment: I think in ChatMessagesController you will be resuing cell, so either you are issing registration or not using cellIdentifier

Comment: I don't think its being issue with Collecitonview or its cell, its because the model class' property is nil

Comment: I thought that from log maybe you should check cellForItemAtIndexPath ?